# Is there a mysql function that will format a unix timestamp?

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a unix timestamp that I would like to convert using mysql if possible. I'd like to have:

```
Mon. May 21st 2009
```

I can of course do this with PHP but why if I can have the database do it. Does a function exist for this?

Thanks.

Comment: Man... a simple Google search solves this! Google for: mysql format unix timestamp

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can look at [FROM_UNIXTIME()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime)

```
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219);
    -> '2007-11-30 10:30:19'
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(1196440219) + 0;
    -> 20071130103019.000000
mysql> SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP(), '%Y %D %M %h:%i:%s %x');
    -> '2007 30th November 10:30:59 2007'
```

To see what specifier you can use, there's a table at [this location.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format)

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT FROM_UNIXTIME(your_column, '%Y-%m-%d') as formatted_time FROM your_table;
```

Returns `your_column` formatted as '2017-08-10';

More formatting options:

```
%a  Abbreviated weekday name (Sun..Sat)
%b  Abbreviated month name (Jan..Dec)
%c  Month, numeric (0..12)
%D  Day of the month with English suffix (0th, 1st, 2nd, 3rd, …)
%d  Day of the month, numeric (00..31)
%e  Day of the month, numeric (0..31)
%f  Microseconds (000000..999999)
%H  Hour (00..23)
%h  Hour (01..12)
%I  Hour (01..12)
%i  Minutes, numeric (00..59)
%j  Day of year (001..366)
%k  Hour (0..23)
%l  Hour (1..12)
%M  Month name (January..December)
%m  Month, numeric (00..12)
%p  AM or PM
%r  Time, 12-hour (hh:mm:ss followed by AM or PM)
%S  Seconds (00..59)
%s  Seconds (00..59)
%T  Time, 24-hour (hh:mm:ss)
%U  Week (00..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 0
%u  Week (00..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 1
%V  Week (01..53), where Sunday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 2; used with %X
%v  Week (01..53), where Monday is the first day of the week; WEEK() mode 3; used with %x
%W  Weekday name (Sunday..Saturday)
%w  Day of the week (0=Sunday..6=Saturday)
%X  Year for the week where Sunday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %V
%x  Year for the week, where Monday is the first day of the week, numeric, four digits; used with %v
%Y  Year, numeric, four digits
%y  Year, numeric (two digits)
%%  A literal % character
%x  x, for any “x” not listed above
```

Answer (score 3):

Look [here](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_from-unixtime). It's called `FROM_UNIXTIME`.